# Add item to Owner Window ListBox

Tags: c#, properties, listbox, window

i'm actually trying to do add an element to an ListBox wich is in the Owner Window

I tried to use the Owner Windows property but i can't access my ListBox.

```
Window parent = this.Owner;
parent.toto.Items.Add();
```

I also tried to add a public property in my Owner Window class (and add the item on the set method), but i can't access it neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the `Owner` property is `Window`.  The compiler doesn't know that it is actually the type you created.  If you perform a cast, and your `ListBox` is **exposed publicly**, you should be able to access it:

```
YourWindowType parent = (YourWindowType)this.Owner;
parent.toto.Items.Add(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> `Window parent = this.ActiveForm;`